# Assigning Two IP addresses to Two separate NIC in VMware ESX 5.5 Server

Tags: vmware-esxi, vmware-esx

I have two ESX 5.5 server. Both have management IP addresses and accessible. For the need of my topology i also connected my ESX servers with LAN cable (Direct LAN Cable) with other interfaces. So that my VMs on both ESX servers can access each other from back side internally.  Now I need to assign IP addresses from command line. I don't have physical access How can I do that?

Comment: You need to make your question MUCH clearer, it's almost impossible to work out what you're trying to do, what your restrictions are and why they are there.

Comment: Why do you think you need to assign IP addresses from the command line?    All that should be done thru the ESXi management client.

Comment: I have fix the issue by creating a vmkenel switch and then add virtual switch. I assigned IP address to vmkernel switch remotely. Thanks.